# Fixed column location in excel macro

Tags: excel

I am new member on this website. I have recorded macro on my "Source" sheet and I just want to fix the location of my columns. In macro I recorded formulas and recorded macro columns are started from G2, H2, I2, J2, K2, L2, M2, BD2, BE2, BF2, CT2, and CU2. Please guide me if you can fixed the location of my columns.

```
Sub ADDDATA()
'
' ADDDATA Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+U
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ST"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(GGG[Unrestricted],GGG[Material],[Component],GGG[Storage Location],""*ST*"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "P"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(GGG[Unrestricted],GGG[Material],[Component],GGG[Storage Location],""*P*"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NET REQ 1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=([ST]+[P])-[Consumption 1]"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NET REQ 2"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=([ST]+[P])-[Consumption 2]"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NET REQ 3"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=([ST]+[P])-[Consumption 3]"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CATEGORY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table5[2],MATCH([@Component],Table5[SAP CODE],0)),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MODEL"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table5[Model],MATCH([@Component],Table5[SAP CODE],0)),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 27
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 31
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 32
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 33
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 34
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 36
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 37
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 39
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 40
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 41
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 42
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 43
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 44
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 45
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 47
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 48
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 49
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 49
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 51
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 53
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 54
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 43).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ETA"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 53
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 51
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 49
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 48
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 49
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table515[ETA],MATCH([@[Purchasing Document38]],Table515[Purchasing Document],0)),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A491")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A491").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ETD"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table515[ETD],MATCH([@[Purchasing Document38]],Table515[Purchasing Document],0)),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A491")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A491").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VESSELS"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table515[Vessel name],MATCH([@[Purchasing Document38]],Table515[Purchasing Document],0)),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A491")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A491").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 207
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 311
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 406
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 428
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 440
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 446
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 471
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 486
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 488
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 489
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 488
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 485
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 454
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 434
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 428
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 426
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 425
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 424
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 421
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 418
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 403
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 388
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 384
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 382
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 380
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 377
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 374
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 372
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 369
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 360
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 352
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 349
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 347
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 344
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 341
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 337
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 334
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 333
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 332
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 330
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 329
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 327
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 325
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 323
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 320
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 318
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 315
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 310
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 307
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 304
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 301
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 297
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 296
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 295
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 294
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 293
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 289
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 283
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 280
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 277
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 274
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 263
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 207
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 202
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 199
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 197
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 193
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 191
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 190
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 188
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 183
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 178
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 172
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 166
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 164
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 162
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 160
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 158
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 157
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 128
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 115
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 96
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 64
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 66
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 74
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 81
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 86
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 87
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 89
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 93
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 98
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 101
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 103
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 104
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 103
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 102
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 101
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 100
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 99
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 98
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 97
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 96
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 95
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 94
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 39).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range( _
        "Table10[[#Headers],[Component]:[Comp. Qty (BUn)]]"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]:[Comp. Qty (BUn)]]").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "JUNE OPENING"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table5[Closing July],MATCH([@Component],Table5[SAP CODE],0)),"""")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "JUNE OPENING PERCENTAGE"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=([JUNE OPENING]/[NET REQ 1])*100"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table10[[#Headers],[Component]]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
End Sub
```

The sample picture is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESMax.png)

Comment: I think you need to start with something more basic when recording the macro so you can start to understand a little bit about what it has done.  You've clearly moved around the worksheet which all gets recorded.  Asking people to sort through all this is unlikely to get you a good result.  So far it shows no effort in resolving the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Clean your code (you can delete all lines that say `ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn`) and hen execute it with F8, line by line. That way you'll see which code line exactly does the column thing and you can change it.